# C++ use function argument type for template argument deduction

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, functor

```
template<typename T>
void f(void (*func)(const T&)) {
    (*func)(T());
}

void func(const int& i) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    f(&func);
}
```

Here the template argument `T (= int)` of `f` is automatically deducted based on the first argument of the function `func`.

Can this also be extended to work with general functors (lambda functions or other function objects.) Possibly with a second function, i.e. something like

```
template<typename T, typename Function> void f(Function func);

template<typename Function>
void call_f(Function func) {
    using arg_type = first_argument_type_t<Function>; // ???
    f<arg_type, Function>(func);
}
```

The fall to `func` in `f` should be able to be inlined by the compiler, so `std::function` cannot be used.

Comment: There are lots of cases to consider for deducing argument type.

Comment: You won't make it in a general case, i.e., if that functor is a generic lambda, or a class-type instance with an overloaded/templated `operator()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use function traits code like [this](https://github.com/sharemind-sdk/cxxheaders/blob/master/src/FunctionTraits.h) (GPL-3 licensed) to do that:

```
template <typename F>
using first_argument_type_t =
     typename sharemind::FunctionTraits<F>::template argument<0u>::type;
```

But there's also the [Boost `function_traits`](http://www.boost.org/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/function_traits.html) alternative, which might be of help.